# Why can't I retrieve a CSS style property for an element using JS?

Tags: javascript, css

So I am trying to retrieve a CSS property from the DOM and the only thing being returned is ""...

e.g. if my CSS code is

```
nav  {
  color: red;
}
```

and my javascript is

```
var nav = document.querySelector("nav");
var navColor = nav.style.color;
console.log(navColor);
```

All that is returned to console is "". I am new to JS.

If I try to manually make a var and find it's property in the console, it also outputs "", until I change the value of the style property, then it successfully returns the properties value - yes I have definitely set a property I am trying to retrieve and I have checked spelling hundreds of times.

Comment: because thats not the class styles thats the inline syles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const { color: classStyle } = getComputedStyle(nav);
const { color: inlineStyle } = nav.style;


console.log(inlineStyle)
console.log(classStyle)
```

```css
nav  {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>this is nav</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `getComputedStyle()` for that:

```
var navColor = getComputedStyle(nav).color;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the applied css rule by calling `getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("nav")).color`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the `style` property only returns inline styles, as in:

```
 <div style="color: red;"></div>
```

would return...

```
 "color: red;"
```

What you're looking for is the [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) function, which can be used to retrieve final style values. Like so:

```
 // HTML
 <div class="some-element"></div>

 // CSS
 .some-element {
      color: red;
 }

 // JS
 const someElement = document.querySelector('.some-element');
 console.log(window.getComputedStyle(someElement).getPropertyValue('color'));
```

This should log out `red`.

**EDIT**

Per comment, the output would actually be `rgb(255, 0, 0)`, the RGB equivalent of red. As the function name suggests, it's *computing* styles, not retrieving their actual values. For example, if you styled with CSS a width to be `10%`, `getComputedStyle` would calculate the pixel value of whatever the final width is rendered as. Not the best solution, but JavaScript generally doesn't need to directly interact with raw CSS files -- that should be up to the CSS and (JavaScript-controlled) classes to manage.

**EDIT 2**

Just an FYI, you can use `.getPropertyValue('color')` or just `.color`, I'm unaware of any preference in the dev community.

Comment: it will log out the rgba value but that should be fine as red is just shorthand for the the rgba value :)

Comment: @JoeWarner Good catch. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var nav = document.querySelector("nav");
console.log(getComputedStyle(nav).color)
```

```css
nav  {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>Menu</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

With .style property You can't access elements css styles if the styles is not inline.

You need to use getComputedStyle function.

Usage:

```
var nav = document.querySelector("nav");
var navColor = getComputedStyle(nav).color;
console.log(navColor);
```

For more information please refer to [this link](http://%20https://zellwk.com/blog/css-values-in-js/)